# How to display the calendar plugin in jQuery mobile without reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
    How to display the calendar plugin in jQuery mobile without reloading?

    [![Were My Calendar is Not Fully loaded][1]][1]

    <a href="#pagefour" data-transition="slideup" onclick="closeNav()">calendar</a>

        <div data-role="page" data-role="main" id="pagefour" class="ui-content">
            <div id="main-page-one">
                <span onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Calendar </span>
                <div id="calendar" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
        <script src='assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
        <script src='assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("calendar").window.location.reload;// Dono how to Load The particular Calendar ID            
            }
        </script>


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Ml1.png
```

when I click The Calendar "Function closeNaV()" my page Used To SlideUp,were calendar plugin in not loaded? 
Can any one Help Me, How to Write a load the "ID" with onClick event in Javascript.

Comment: can you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to Load My Calendar ID,When I click on the id="PageFour".

Answer (score 0):

Put your calendar loading code here

```
$('#PageFour').click(function (){
    //load calendar code
});
```